# How to pass JSON to the Web Service wanted

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, thymeleaf

I want to take a input from a html webpage and post it to the web service. The problem currently is that it keep failing, so I wish to ask that is there any logic error in the codes. We are using AJAX to post the data to the web service, after successful, it will be then redirect to view-joke.html

add-jokes.html

```
<body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Question</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="theSetup" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Answer</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="thePunchline" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        
        <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
          var question = document.getElementById("theSetup").value; 
          var answer = document.getElementById("thePunchline").value;
         var jokemodel = {
            
            setup : question,
            punchline : answer
         };
         
         var requestJSON = JSON.stringify(jokemodel);
         $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/useJokes",
            headers : {
               "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            data : requestJSON,
            success : function(data) {
               window.location.href ='view-jokes.html';
            },
            error : function(data) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
    </body>
```

view-jokes.html

```
<body>
            
<div id="jokeJson">
    
</div>

        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/useJokes", function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                        $("#jokeJson").append(value.setup + " " + value.punchline + " ");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

This is our web service

```
@RestController
public class jokeController {
    
   private static Map<String, jokeModel> jokeRepo = new HashMap<>();
   static {
      jokeModel jokeNo1 = new jokeModel("title","punchline");
      
      jokeRepo.put(jokeNo1.getSetup(), jokeNo1);
      
      jokeModel jokeNo2 = new jokeModel("title2","punchline2");

      jokeRepo.put(jokeNo2.getSetup(), jokeNo2);
   }
    
    
     @RequestMapping(value = "/useJokes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> createJoke(@RequestBody jokeModel jokeModelObj) {
      jokeRepo.put(jokeModelObj.getSetup(), jokeModelObj);
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Product is created successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }
   
      @RequestMapping(value = "/useJokes")
   public ResponseEntity<Object> getJokes() {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(jokeRepo.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine. But if you want to be helped with your error, you may want to post more details about your error.

Comment: the ajax cannot post the data successfully because it always run this line
error : function(data) {
                alert("Failed");

instead of 
data : requestJSON,
            success : function(data) {
               window.location.href ='view-jokes.html';

Comment: and if you remove the function that hides the error?

Comment: still the same....

Comment: What error are you getting from the ajax response? Your browser tools (F12) will show you that information. Also, if the browser shows the error code as status "500", then the server (whatever is listening on http://localhost:8080) should also have logged its own error. You can [edit] your question to show us all of these details.